# jquery mobile theme roller - is there a way to use theme roller to control all possible html element?

Tags: jquery-mobile

is it true to say that jquery mobile's themeroller only gives one the options to define swatches for those finite set of elements that are on the themeroller screen (http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/)?  There is no way to use theme roller to define style of other html element, such as .

Answer (score 1):

Well jqm mainly enhances the buttons and links. So it promotes all the elements to button types by wrapping them like list items and selectmenus. and these things you can easily change using themeroller. But if you want to style buttons differently then you'll have to use jqm classes and override their styling.
Common classes are

```
ui-btn : to override button styles
ui-body: to override background styles
ui-listview: to override list styling
ui-header/footer : to override header/footer
ui-content : to override content settings
ui-btn-icon : to override icons
ui-navbar : to override navbar styling
```

And other customizable options can be available on their demos site
[JQM Demos](http://demos.jquerymobile.com)

Comment: so, there is no way to use themeroller's interactive tool to create style for  html tag like  <label>?  What I'm hoping for is that I'll create the html page without specified my own style class.  Once I'm done, I can then ask designer to go the themeroller to create the style that he/she wants.

Comment: This can't be done in jqm. I also wanted this once but what i ended up with was adding `data-role="none"` to the widgets which i wanted to design myself.